# Align Vertically and Horizontally with Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm following the documentation on https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment.

I'm trying to align my div vertically and horizontally, it works for horizontal alignment but not for vertical. Source of the div is below:

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="text-center">
  <md-content>
    <h2>Test h2</h2>
  </md-content>
  <form ng-controller="LoginController as login" ng-submit="login.login()"
    ng-cloak class="text-center">
    <md-content>
      Login or ,<br/>
      register test br
      <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Your email address</label>
        <input ng-model="login.user.email" type="email" required>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Your password</label>
        <input ng-model="login.user.password" type="password" required>
      </md-input-container>
      <div class="md-block">
        <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Log in</md-button>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </form>
</div>
```

What is the problem here? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/aCZFrBrY5xYvvFgThRvn?p=preview

Take a look at the main divs after `layout="column"` and row. They are important.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="app" layout="column" flex>
  <div flex layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="text-center">
    <div>
      <md-content>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
          <h2>Test h2</h2>
        </div>
      </md-content>
      <form ng-controller="MainController as login" ng-submit="login.login()" ng-cloak class="text-center">
        <md-content>
          <p>Some random text is here, login or register</p>
          <div layout="row" layout-align="center start">
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
              <label style="text-align:center">Your email address</label>
              <input ng-model="login.user.email" type="email" required>
            </md-input-container>
          </div>
          <div layout="row" layout-align="center start">
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
              <label style="text-align:center">Your password</label>
              <input ng-model="login.user.password" type="password" required>
            </md-input-container>
          </div>
          <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
            <div class="md-block">
              <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Log in</md-button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </md-content>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

angular.module('app').controller('MainController', ["$scope", function($scope) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<div layout-align='center center' layout='column'>
```

This will align center only to immediate child element. So wrap all element to  which you want to align horizontal and vertically center

```
<div layout-align='center center' layout='column'>
     <div>ABC</div>
     <div>XYZ</div>
</div>
```